# node-amqp cannot send message to RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp

I'm tring [rabbitmq-tutorials](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials), ruby version works fine, but node.js version cannot send message. I do not know what is wrong.

```
var amqp       = require('amqp');
var amqp_hacks = require('./amqp-hacks');

var connection = amqp.createConnection({host: 'localhost'});

connection.on('ready', function(){
    connection.publish('hello_node', 'Hello World!');
    console.log(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'");

    amqp_hacks.safeEndConnection(connection);
});
```

after I run `node send.js`, runing process `node recv.js` cannot recv anything. and `rabbitmqctl list_queues` does not show `hello_node` queues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to indicate the queue then publish.
That version should works:

```
    var amqp       = require('amqp');
    var amqp_hacks = require('./amqp-hacks');

    var connection = amqp.createConnection({host: 'localhost'});

    connection.on('ready', function(){
            connection.queue('hello_node', {'durable': false}, function(q){
                connection.publish('hello_node', 'Hello World!');
                console.log(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!' to 'hello_node'");

                amqp_hacks.safeEndConnection(connection);
            });
    });
```